# Problem viewing application changes using update() function

Tags: c++, qt

I'm starting to learn programming with qt and to become familiar with the library I'm making easy little programs. One of these plans to create QLabels, which should be added to the app each time a button is pressed, but I don't understand why they don't appear. Here is the code:

file .h:

```
class Base : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Base(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Base();

public slots:
    void AddWidget();

private:
    QVBoxLayout *Vlayout;
};
```

file .cpp

```
Base::Base(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    Vlayout=new QVBoxLayout(this);

    QPushButton *l=new QPushButton("+",this);

    Vlayout->addWidget(l);

    connect(l,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(AddWidget()));
}

Base::~Base()
{}

void Base::AddWidget(){

    Vlayout->addWidget(new QLabel("Added",this));
    Vlayout->update();
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with your code. Maybe, there's something wrong with the code you didn't expose. (Or if there is no other code then there is missing something essentially like e.g. function `main()`.) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must be missing in OPs code.

Additionally, the call of `Vlayout->update()` isn't necessary in my opinion.

I made an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate:

`testQWidgetAdd.cc`:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Test Add Widget");
  QVBoxLayout qVBox;
  QPushButton qBtn("Add QLabel");
  qVBox.addWidget(&qBtn);
  qWinMain.setLayout(&qVBox);
  qWinMain.show();
  int i = 1;
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qBtn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    [&](bool) {
      qVBox.addWidget(new QLabel(QString("QLabel %1").arg(i++)));
    });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(QWidgetAdd)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_executable(testQWidgetAdd testQWidgetAdd.cc)

target_link_libraries(testQWidgetAdd Qt5::Widgets)
```

Output:

[image: snapshot of testQWidgetAdd.exe]

and after clicking multiple times on button "Add QLabel":

[image: snapshot of testQWidgetAdd.exe]

---

Upon request, OP provided the [**complete code on pastebin**](https://pastebin.com/vsP1SLRJ) there I extracted the following snippet from:

```
Base::Base(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QHBoxLayout* Hlayout=new QHBoxLayout(this);
    Vlayout=new QVBoxLayout(this);

    QPushButton *m=new QPushButton("exit",this);
    QPushButton *l=new QPushButton("+",this);

    Hlayout->addWidget(l);
    Hlayout->addWidget(m);

    Vlayout->addLayout(Hlayout);

    connect(l,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(AddWidget()));
    connect(m,SIGNAL(clicked()),qApp,SLOT(quit()));

    m->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    l->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
}
```

and this is specifically the broken part:

```
    QHBoxLayout* Hlayout=new QHBoxLayout(this);
    Vlayout=new QVBoxLayout(this);
```

The explanation step-by-step:

- `class Base` is derived from `QWidget`. Hence, layout management of `QWidget` applies.
- `QWidget` supports one layout to manage the placement and size of children.
  It has to be applied by [**QWidget::setLayout()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout). Excerpt from doc:

  > If there already is a layout manager installed on this widget, QWidget won't let you install another.
- A layout may be constructed with or without parent widget.

If a layout is constructed *with* a (pointer to) parent widget the layout is set to the widget "implicitly". Otherwise, it has to be set explicitly (with `QWidget::setLayout()`) or can be added to another layout.

Though, I personally prefer to always set the layout explicitly (but that might be a matter of taste).

The actual mistake of OP: `Hlayout` *and* `Vlayout` are constructed with `this` but there cannot be set two layouts to `this`. So, the second is ignored.

Hence, widgets which are added to `Vlayout` cannot become visible because `Vlayout` is not set in `this` and the `QLabel`s cannot become children of `this`.

A possible fix:

Instead of

```
    QHBoxLayout* Hlayout=new QHBoxLayout(this);
```

it has to be

```
    QHBoxLayout* Hlayout=new QHBoxLayout();
```

The line to add the `Hlayout` to the `Vlayout` is already there (but didn't have the intended effect before):

```
    Vlayout->addLayout(Hlayout);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Here I put the link to my complete program, I don't know if this goes against the rules, in case it is I will remove it as soon as possible. [link](https://pastebin.com/vsP1SLRJ)

Comment: @E.sk.ovf Answer extended.